# Problem with a code

Tags: programming

I have one problem with my code and I'm a beginner and I can't solve it. Can you help me? Thank you so much.

I have this problem:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
```

And this is my code:

```
int trigPin = 12;
int echoPin = 11;
long timeperiod, cm;
const int analogOutPin = 9;
int brightness;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop(){

  if (timeperiod > 50)
  analogWrite(analogOutPin,0);
}
{

  if (timeperiod 10 < 50){
  for(brightness = 0; brightness < 256; brightness++){
    analogWrite(led,brightness);
    delay(10);}
}}
  if (timeperiod < 10)
  analogWrite(analogOutPin,0);

{
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(20);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(0);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  timeperiod = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(timeperiod);
  Serial.print("dist=");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.println();

  delay(10);
}
long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds)
{ 
  return microseconds / 74 /2;
}
  long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
  return microseconds / 29/ 2;
}
```

Comment: Sort out your indenting and you will find that the brackets you have don't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can see in your code is that your code modules are starting and ending anywhere. See from where till where you want to run a particular line of code. If you writing this code on arduino IDE you will be able to see which the ending of a particular bracket when you keep the cursor on one.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the first 5 lines:

```
void loop(){

  if (timeperiod > 50)
  analogWrite(analogOutPin,0);
}
{
```

Always align your braces, you can do it like this:

```
 xxx {
    yyy
 }
```

or

```
 xxx
 {
    yyy
 }
```

where xxx and yyy can be one or more statements.

If you align the first 5 lines correctly, you see you should add a {:

```
if (timeperiod > 50)
{ // <- added
    analogWrite(analogOutPin,0);
}
```

Also, if you have an if, for or while statement, ALWAYS add brackets, even if it is only one line. Thus:

```
if (timeperiod > 50)
    analogWrite(analogOutPin,0);
```

should be written as

```
if (timeperiod > 50)
{
    analogWrite(analogOutPin,0);
}
```

This is not a mandatory rule, but if you later misindent something, or add a new line in the body, it is easily forgotten to add the brackets, so you better can do it beforehand.

So (also), it is wise to

- align brackets (like explained above)
- always use brackets in if/while/loop statements.
- always use the same amount of spaces (or a tab) to indent a new level (e.g. after an if, while, loop, or the body of a function).
- use new lines between functions; this makes it much easier to read
- split up big functions with many brackets, in (sub) functions/methods (not in your case, yet)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did all of this and it says that I have the same mistake!

Comment: @jupepi Edit your question and post your new, aligned and clean code.

Comment: I don't see your code changes yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems start here:

```
void loop(){

  if (timeperiod > 50)
  analogWrite(analogOutPin,0);
}
{
```

You are missing an opening brace for your if statement, and then have an extra opening brace afterwords. Also, any code inside braces should be indented from the code before it:

```
void loop(){

  if (timeperiod > 50) {
    analogWrite(analogOutPin,0);
  }

  if (timeperiod 10 < 50){
    for(brightness = 0; brightness < 256; brightness++) {
      analogWrite(led,brightness);
      delay(10);
    }
  } 
  //And the rest of your loop function also needs cleanup...
```

The rest of your loop function needs cleanup as well. You've got bad indentation and mismatched braces all over the place. As @Majenko says in their comment, if you clean up your code formatting then your syntax problems will be obvious.